# Calling a COM function crashes and I can't figure out why

Tags: c#, c++, com

I have a C# .NET Framework application that comes along with a C# DLL that has COM interfaces. The COM interfaces are published by registering them in the Windows Registry.

When starting, the C# application starts a C++ application and establishes a communication with it (using NamedPipes). Then, the C++ application calls a function from one of the registered COM interfaces.

I have added a new function to the existing interface, re-compiled all projects, registered the updated DLL in the Windows Registry and when I everything as before, it works totally fine. However, when I use the new function my C++ application crashes - and I can't figure out why.

There is no error in the Windows Event Log and I know that the crash happens when I call "_intf->FunctionV2". Calling "_intf->Function" works fine. I added a try-catch-block around it, but I have not caught anything.

Any ideas?

```
try
{
    _comClientAdapter->AddLog(L"Namespace::Function - pre", TRUE);

    result = _intf->FunctionV2(kontext, pCollection, TRUE);
    // result = _intf->Function(kontext, pCollection);

    _comClientAdapter->AddLog(L"Namespace::Function - post", TRUE);
}
catch (const std::overflow_error& e)
{
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << L"Namespace::Function - overflow_error - " << e.what();

    _comClientAdapter->AddLog(wss.str().c_str(), TRUE);
}
catch (const std::runtime_error& e)
{
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << L"Namespace::Function - runtime_error - " << e.what();

    _comClientAdapter->AddLog(wss.str().c_str(), TRUE);
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << L"Namespace::Function - exception - " << e.what();

    _comClientAdapter->AddLog(wss.str().c_str(), TRUE);
}
catch (std::string s)
{
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << L"Namespace::Function - exception - " << s.c_str();

    _comClientAdapter->AddLog(wss.str().c_str(), TRUE);
}
catch (std::wstring ws)
{
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << L"Namespace::Function - exception - " << ws.c_str();

    _comClientAdapter->AddLog(wss.str().c_str(), TRUE);
}
catch (int i)
{
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << L"Namespace::Function - exception - " << i;

    _comClientAdapter->AddLog(wss.str().c_str(), TRUE);
}
catch (long l)
{
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << L"Namespace::Function - exception - " << l;

    _comClientAdapter->AddLog(wss.str().c_str(), TRUE);
}
catch (unsigned long ul)
{
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << L"Namespace::Function - exception - " << ul;

    _comClientAdapter->AddLog(wss.str().c_str(), TRUE);
}
catch (...)
{
    _comClientAdapter->AddLog(L"Namespace::Function - exception - UNKNOWN", TRUE);

    IErrorInfo* pError;
    unsigned long result = GetErrorInfo(0, &pError);

    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << L"Namespace::Function - exception - COM Error Result = ";

    if (SUCCEEDED(result) && pError)
    {
        // Build an error message from the COM error object
        BSTR bstrSource = NULL;
        if (SUCCEEDED(pError->GetSource(&bstrSource)) && bstrSource)
        {
            _bstr_t src(bstrSource, false);
            wss << static_cast<const char*>(src) <<  " : ";
        }

        BSTR bstrDesc = NULL;
        if (SUCCEEDED(pError->GetDescription(&bstrDesc)) && bstrDesc)
        {
            wss << " - ";
            _bstr_t desc(bstrDesc, false);
            wss << static_cast<const char*>(desc);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wss << L"GetErrorInfo failed";
    }

    _comClientAdapter->AddLog(wss.str().c_str(), TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Probably the COM registry is finding an old version of the C# DLL that still implements the old version of the interface.  That's why in COM adding new functions typically involves interface inheritance, not making changes to existing interfaces.

Comment: If you *ARE* going to modify your interfaces, do yourself a favor and make the next function you add be a very simple one that returns a version number.

Comment: "*I have added a new function to the existing interface*" - DON'T DO THAT IN COM! Once an interface is in use, DON'T CHANGE IT. When you need to add functions, or make changes to existing functions, add them as new interfaces instead. This way, existing clients that don't know/care about the new functions/changes don't need to be recompiled, and new clients that want to use the new functions/changes can simply query for the new interfaces as needed. This is a core concept to COM's stabilty, so you need to follow it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am forced to work in the way my employer wants me to work. I could not resolve the reason for my problem. However, when I registered the DLL that was created by the build server it worked. I do neither now the source of the problem nor the solution, but I can work now.